# Код выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Выдаёт ошибку с tkinter, делаю словарик, не могу понять, что не правильно

```
from tkinter import *
    text = open('slovar.txt', 'w+')
    words = {}
    perevod_word = ''
    perevod_word1 = ''
    def update1(dict):
        with open("slovar.txt") as file:
            for line in file:
                key, *value = line.split()
                words[key] = value
    def rus1():
        global perevod_word
        perevod_word = entrus2.get()
    def eng1():
        global perevod_word1
        perevod_word1 = enteng2.get()
    def rus():
        slovo1 = entrus1.get()
        if slovo1 in words:
            print(words.get(slovo1))
        else:
            print('Не найдено')
            print('Введите значение слова по Английски')
            rus1()
            perevod1 = perevod_word
            slovo1, perevod1 = perevod1, slovo1
            words[slovo1] = perevod1
            up = slovo1 + ' : ' + perevod1 + ', '
            text.write(up)
        print(words)
    def eng():
        slovo2 = enteng1.get()
        eng_words=dict([[v, k] for k,v in words.items()])
        if slovo2 in eng_words:
            print(eng_words.get(y))
        else:
            print('Не найдено')
            print('Введите значение слова по Русски')
            eng1()
            perevod2 = perevod_word1
            words[slovo2] = perevod2
            up = slovo2 + ' : ' + perevod2 + ', '
            text.write(up)
        print(words)
    def w2():
        d = Tk()
        d.geometry('200x200')
        d.title('Русско-английский')
        te = Text(d, text='Введите слово:')
        te.grid()
        entrus1 = Entry(d)
        entrus1.grid()
        button_check = Button(d, text='Ready!', command=rus)
        button_check.grid()
        entrus2 = Entry(d)
        entrus2.grid()
        button_check1 = Button(d, text='Ready!', command=rus1)
        button_check1.grid()
        d.mainloop()
    def w1():
        k = Tk()
        k.geometry('200x200')
        k.title('Англо-русский')
        te = Text(k, text='Введите слово:')
        te.grid()
        ent = Entry(k)
        ent.grid()
        button_check = Button(k, text='Ready!', command=eng)
        button_check.grid()
        k.mainloop()
    def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Переводчик')
        root.geometry('400x400')
        but1 = Button(root, text='Русско-английский', command=w2)
        but1.grid()
        but2 = Button(root, text='Англо-русский', command=w1)
        but2.grid()
        root.mainloop()
    def glav():
        update1(words)
        main()
    glav()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно заполняете Text виджет

```
te = Text(d)
te.insert(END, 'Введите слово:')
```

Comment: я перепутал виджет text с виджетом label 